# Attempting to retrieve only the values, not the keys

Tags: javascript

I am working on this code below. I am attempting to retrieve only the values, not the keys. What this is not doing is providing me with the values but the keys. Can you help me to get this to work properly?
Unfortunately I cannot use the object.values() function, therefore I am at a loss right now. Sorry This was not stated when I posted the original.

```
function values(obj) {
    let arr = [];
    for (let value in obj) {
      arr.push(value);
    }
    return arr;
  }
let nicknames = {a:`Sunny`, b:`Weirdo`, c:`Chicken`,d:`Tokyo`}
let nicknameValues = values(nicknames)
console.log(nicknameValues)
```

Comment: This is JavaScript, not Java. They are very different programming languages.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in, that's what's supposed to happen.

Comment: Object.values(obj)......

Comment: @RobinZigmond If I were to use the for...of wouldn't I need to change the obj since ```obj is not iterable?

Comment: How can you be at a loss when you haven't tried google? Second result is a question that matches this one exactly.

Comment: @Billy.Brown0618 sorry, you're right

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
arr.push(obj[value]);
```

**Demo:**

```js
function values(obj) {
    let arr = [];
    for (let value in obj) {
      arr.push(obj[value]);
    }
    return arr;
  }
let nicknames = {a:`Sunny`, b:`Weirdo`, c:`Chicken`,d:`Tokyo`}
let nicknameValues = values(nicknames)
console.log(nicknameValues);
```

Or

```
const result = Object.values({a:`Sunny`, b:`Weirdo`, c:`Chicken`,d:`Tokyo`});
console.log(result);
```

**Demo:**

```js
const result = Object.values({a:`Sunny`, b:`Weirdo`, c:`Chicken`,d:`Tokyo`});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance! It worked like a charm!
Thanks for noticing that I could use `object.values`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.values`:

```js
const values = Object.values({a:`Sunny`, b:`Weirdo`, c:`Chicken`,d:`Tokyo`});

console.log(values);
```

Or you can change you function `values`

```
arr.push(obj[value]);
```